# Are the color and brightness of a camera's LCD accurate?

Tags: display-calibration, monitors, rear-lcd, lcd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don’t you need to calibrate a camera’s LCD screen?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19013/why-dont-you-need-to-calibrate-a-cameras-lcd-screen)

I guess $100 cameras have cheap LCDs. What about more expensive "creative compacts" (like Coolpix P6000, Canon G11, etc.?), mirrorless and SLRs? Is the LCD of a good camera better than an average laptop LCD screen or not?

My Canon 400D display has good viewing angle so I guess it might be IPT, but on the other hand underexposed photos looks fine on the LCD to me, while they look dark on my laptop screen (and really are dark - it is not fault of the laptop screen).

Answer (score 5):

No, the camera LCD is not better than a laptop screen. Often the gamut of the camera LCD is smaller than a laptop, too. This [article](http://cameras.about.com/od/technologies/a/Using-Camera-Lcd-Screens.htm) discusses some of the issues around the camera LCD.

Another factor that you didn't mention but should consider is monitor calibration. If your laptop's display has not been calibrated then you really need to address that first before doing anything else. There are many products and techniques out there for calibration. Here is one [instructional guide](http://digital-photography-school.com/how-to-calibrate-your-monitor) but there are many others on the web. In each case, though, you will need to obtain a hardware calibration device such as a [Spyder](http://spyder.datacolor.com/portfolio-view/spyder4express/) from Colorvision or [ColorMunki](http://xritephoto.com/ph_product_overview.aspx?id=1115) from Xrite (there are other ones besides these).